# Drastic re-arranging via svn

Tags: svn, bash, file

So I am doing pretty drastic re-arranging of files through SVN. By drastic I mean moving dozens of folders at a time and creating dozens more. I am having a lot of trouble wrestling with SVN. Part of it is I keep forgetting to use 'svn mv' and the other relevant svn commands. Part of this though is the built in tools (find, xargs, etc...) give me more power to do certain things.

To make a long story short I keep getting situations where I move a directory and the source destination appears flagged as '!' and the new destination as '?' which makes sense. However, when I try to add the new destination marked '?' it says it's already under subversion. I am assuming it's .svn directory is causing problem but if I delete it then I get "not a working copy" error.

So the higher level question is, am I stuck with svn mv, svn delete, svn mkdir, etc...?
I have searched and found references to git-svn but it is not an option. Any advice for large re-arranging of files via svn? Is there an equivalent to something like:

find . -type d -name somefolder -exec touch somefile \;

Using svn commands to not cause trouble.
Or more relevant, if I'm doing edits like these:

mkdir -p {a,b,c}/{d,e}/f

How do I do that using svn mkdir?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your current problem, you could delete the `.svn` directories from the moved folders. After that you can add them again.

But I would really recommend to use `svn mv` instead since you lose the reference to the version history of a file otherwise.

> Using svn commands to not cause trouble. Or more relevant, if I'm doing edits like these:
>
> mkdir -p {a,b,c}/{d,e}/f

You could try this:

```
mkdir -p {a,b,c}/{d,e}/f
svn add {a,b,c}/{d,e}/f
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Although I noticed one limitation just now. What if I need to do `{a,b,c}/*/{d,e}`? Right now mkdir is making a new directory with `*` as its name. Is there a way to "escape" the `*` and have it interpret it as 'everything in this folder'.

Comment: @YGomez: I think I answered my own question. Seems:
`for A in {a,b,c}; do for B in ${A}/*; do mkdir ${B}/f; done; done;`

Does the job. I am not sure if this is a horrible way to do it though.

Comment: @YGomez: something like `*/non-existing_path` will never work because the shell won't find the non-existing part. I think a loop is indeed the easiest option here.

Answer (score 0):

I often use `xargs` when doing large svn operations and I don't find that very limiting compared to using ordinary commands.